# How can I visualize orbits given Earth-centered, inertial (ECI) coordinates?

Tags: orbit, simulation, visualization

I'm using the SGP4 algorithm which outputs Earth-centered, inertial (ECI) satellite coordinates. 
I found some software to visualize orbits, but they all request input as Keplerian elements.

How can I have 3D visual simulations of earth and the satellite orbit, animated or not, from the ECI-time data I have?

Comment: Is there anything here (any of the answers) that can help: [Software tools for space exploration available online](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/790/12102)?